# Hedonic price method multivariate regression in R | Interpretation of linear-linear, log-linear and log-log model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am aware that there are similar questions on this site, however, none of them seem to answer my question sufficiently.

I am performing a multivariate regression in order to predict real estate data using Hedonic price method.

[EXCERPT OF DATA USED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VpgZ.png)

Dependent variable is *AV_TOTAL*, which is actually the price of the unit apartments'.

Distances from the closer park/highway are expressed in meters.

*U_NUM_PARKS/U_FPLACE*(presence of parkings and fireplace) are taken into account as dummy variables.

1) Linear-Linear Model --> [Results Model 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLpEX.png)

```
lm(AV_TOTAL ~ LIVINGA_AREAM2 + NUM_FLOORS + 
        U_BASE_FLO + U_BDRMS + factor(U_NUM_PARK) + DIST_PARKS + 
        DIST_HIGHdiff + DIST_BIGDIG, data = data)
```

[Residuals Model 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLqq.png)

2) Log-linear Model --> [Results Model 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUf1H.png)

```
lm(log(AV_TOTAL) ~ LIVINGA_AREAM2 + NUM_FLOORS + 
        U_BASE_FLO + U_BDRMS + factor(U_NUM_PARK) + DIST_PARKS + DIST_HIGHdiff + DIST_BIGDIG, data = data)
```

[Residuals Model 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dflL.png)

3) Log-Log Model --> [Results Model 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVtKy.png)

```
lm(formula = log(AV_TOTAL) ~ log(LIVINGA_AREAM2) + NUM_FLOORS + 
    U_BASE_FLO + log(U_BDRMS) + factor(U_NUM_PARK) + log(DIST_PARKS) + 
    log(DIST_HIGHdiff) + log(DIST_BIGDIG), data = data)
```

[Residuals Model 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzgH9.png)

All the models have quite good R^2 while residuals plot shows better normal distribution for Model 2 and 3.

I can't figure out which is the difference between model 2 and 3 especially in interpreting the variable `DIST_PARKS` (distance from parks) and also which is the more correct model.

Comment: Welcome to stack. Thank you for the effort. Try to consider giving an reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example : give a part of your dataset using `dput` or create a toy data set), and avoid the external link to images. Prefer to gives the meaningful part of your result in your question. You maybe should consider cross validated instead of SO : https://stats.stackexchange.com/